# django - load currently logged in user information in the form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

django noob here.
The question i am going to ask has been asked several times, however, i couldn't find the answers which can help my case.

the query is:
I have a Form having a choice field which loads its choices information from the database. Basically, I have designed my models in such a way that, the choices displayed is individual to the users.

for example:
for user1, the choice field shows a,b,c,d.
where as for user 2, the choice field shows v,w,d.

The problem i am facing is referencing the logged in user and getting the username. then pass the username as the filter to the database.

I have come across numerous **init** functions trying to do this, somehow it is not helping my case.

**forms.py**

```
class class_model(forms.Form):
    class_name = forms.ChoiceField(
                    required=False,
                    widget=forms.Select,
                )

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super (class_model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        current_user = self.user
        name = current_user.username
        k = User.objects.get(username=name)
        y = UserProfile.objects.get(user=k)
        schoolid = y.schoolid
        primary_filter = Class1.objects.filter (school_id=schoolid)
        ax = [("Choose Class", "Choose Class")] + list (primary_filter.objects.values_list ('class_name', 'class_name').distinct())
        self.fields['class_name'].choices = ax
```

The error i receive: `'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'username'`

**Update:**

**views.py**

```
            @login_required(login_url="login/")
            def create(request):
                print(request.method)
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    form2 = class_model(request.POST, request.user)
                    if form2.is_valid():
                        class_name = form2.cleaned_data['class_name']
                    return render(request, 'create_student.html', {'form2': form2}
                else:       
                    print(form.errors)
                    return render(request, 'create_student.html', {'form2': form2})
```

Comment: You need to show how you are instantiating this form in the view, in particular what you are passing as the user parameter.

Comment: Updated with the view. 
Please let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: Found an answer!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405631/how-to-get-currently-logged-user-id-in-form-model-in-django-1-7

Answer (score 0):

You've told the form to expect the user as the first positional parameter, so you need to pass it there.

```
form2 = class_model(request.user, data=request.POST)
```

Comment: I tried it.
The error still persists.
I receive a "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects'" error.

Does the error has anything to do with the form (how I am trying to load the user information in the init function?)

Comment: Any help will be really appreciated. Requesting assistance with this query.

Comment: Please show the updated code and the full traceback, as an edit to your question.