# Update record using model form in django

Tags: django, modelform, updatemodel

HI I am updating an existing record, but everytime I do, its is saying 
`Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'user1'`
I am pasting my view and models here. Please help me

**Model**

```
class BasicDetails(models.Model):
   username = models.OneToOneField(User)
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Name")
   sex = models.CharField(max_length = 10, verbose_name = "Sex", choices = GENDER_CHOICES)
   dob = models.DateField(verbose_name = "Date of Birth")

   class Meta:
      db_table = u'wed_basicdetails'
   def __unicode__(self):
         return u'%s' % (self.username)
```

**View**

```
def editbasicdetails(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
      username = User.objects.filter(username = request.user)
      instance = get_object_or_404(User, username = username)
      form = EditBasicDetailsForm(request.POST,instance=instance)
      if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/myprofile/')
  else:
      form = EditBasicDetailsForm(request.user)
  return shortcuts.render_to_response('editbasicdetails.html',locals(),
                                    context_instance = context.RequestContext(request))
```

**Model Form**

```
class EditBasicDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self,user, *args, **kwargs):
      super(EditBasicDetailsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

      userid = User.objects.filter(username = user).values('id')[0].get('id')
      self.fields['username'] = forms.CharField(initial = user,
                                              widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'readonly':'readonly'}))
  class Meta:
      model = BasicDetails
```

In the above view, I am not passing the username I am just getting the username value from `request.user` I am not sure what I am making wrong on this simple functionality.

-Vikram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably related to the inconsistent behavior of the form wrt model. Since, the database stores the OneToOneField as integer and CharField as varchar.

You don't have to override the form **init** method. You could do it directly with the initial argument.

```
form = EditBasicDetailsForm(initial = {'username' : request.user)
```

Update:

In your view code I would suggest you to properly intend you HttpResponseRedirect statement. Otherwise, if the form is in valid it won't display it again.

```
if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/myprofile/')
```

Comment: Hi Raunak, Do u want me to change the form? and I have added the above line in the if condition but the error still persists

Comment: Yeah can you remove the __init__ method if not and try again!

Comment: I am using the init method in order retrieve the existing values from the database. In the above question, I have posted only the username in the form but I have all the fields `self.fields['fieldname']`

Comment: But you don't have to if you use the initial argument its going to take care of that. Moreover, the object which you are trying to fetch from the database would be the same as of the request as in the Middleware takes care of that.

Comment: Can you please show us the complete error along with the location of error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20827/discussion-between-raunak-agarwal-and-vikram)

Comment: After following this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202839/get-request-data-in-django-form I got the solution