# User specific data in automatic generated forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

My code is pretty simple and straight forward. These are my **forms**

```
class LearningObjectiveForm( ModelForm ):
  class Meta:
    model = LearningObjective
    fields = ( 'learning_objective', 'topic', )
```

this is a snippet from my **template**

```
<form method="POST" action=".">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ form }}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Speichern"/>
</form>
```

this form makes now every topic access able for every user. Since this field normally has a user restriction, I don't want that every topic is shown but just the topic for a certain user. The structure in my **models** for this specific case look like this

```
class Trainee( models.Model ):
  user = models.OneToOneField( User )
  first_name = models.TextField()
  last_name = models.TextField()
  education_beginning = models.DateField()
  comment = models.TextField( null = True, blank = True )

class Topic( models.Model ):
  trainee = models.ForeignKey( Trainee )
  topic = models.TextField()

class LearningObjective( models.Model ):
  trainee = models.ForeignKey( Trainee )
  topic = models.ManyToManyField( Topic, blank = True, null = True)
  learning_objective = models.TextField()
```

And my **views**

```
class LearningObjectiveView( LoginRequiredMixin, FormView ):
  form_class = LearningObjectiveForm( user = request.user )
  success_url = reverse_lazy( 'learning_objective' )
  template_name = 'learningobjective.html'

  def get_context_data( self, **kwargs ):
    trainee = Trainee.objects.get( user = self.request.user )
    context = super( LearningObjectiveView, self ).get_context_data( **kwargs )
    context['learningobjective'] = LearningObjective.objects.filter( trainee = trainee.id )
    context['topic'] = Topic.objects.filter( trainee = trainee.id )
    return context

  def form_valid( self, form ):
    self.object = form.save( commit = False )
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
      self.object.trainee = Trainee.objects.get( user = self.request.user )
    self.object.save()
    return super( LearningObjectiveView, self ).form_valid( form )
```

Topics should be trainee specific. Do I have to write my own form in the template or is there such a way so that I still can auto generate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the queryset attribute of the [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) in the form init function and that will limit the choices as well as validate correctly.

The form will look something like the following code

```
class LearningObjectiveForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = LearningObjective
    fields = ('learning_objective', 'topic',)

  def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(LearningObjectiveForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['topic'].queryset = Topic.objects.filter(trainee=user)
```

And then in the form make sure to call the form with the user `LearningObjectiveForm(user=request.user)`

Comment: Note that `trainee` is _not_ a foreign key to `User` either.

Comment: How are you linking the trainee to the User then? How do you know which trainee the request user is?

Comment: Ok yeah that approach is going to get you in a LOT of trouble. Take a look at  extending the user model. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model 

You can't tell which trainee is using the app with this approach.

Comment: you need to call the form with the request argument, or actually it would be better to pass in the request.user object at this point. Here's an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202839/get-request-data-in-django-form

Comment: ok so you're using CBV, it's different with that (you didn't post anything showing that)... search how to get request in CBV, you're going to have to override the  get_form_class method

Answer (score 0):

In addition to awwester's answer I added this to my **view**

```
class LearningObjectiveView( LoginRequiredMixin, FormView ):
    form_class = LearningObjectiveForm
    template_name = 'learningobjective.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy( 'learning_objective' )

    def get_context_data( self, **kwargs ):
        trainee = Trainee.objects.get( user = self.request.user )
        context = super( LearningObjectiveView, self ).get_context_data( **kwargs )
        context['learningobjective'] = LearningObjective.objects.filter( trainee = trainee.id )
        context['topic'] = Topic.objects.filter( trainee = trainee.id )
        return context

    def get_form_kwargs( self ):
        kwargs = super( LearningObjectiveView , self ).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def form_valid( self, form ):
        self.object = form.save( commit = False )
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            self.object.trainee = Trainee.objects.get( user = self.request.user )
        self.object.save()
        return super( LearningObjectiveView, self ).form_valid( form )
```

The `get_form_kwargs` passes the kwarg user with the current user to the form.
Then my Form finally looked like this:

```
class LearningObjectiveForm( ModelForm ):
    def __init__( self, user, *args, **kwargs ):
        trainee = Trainee.objects.get( user = user )
        super( LearningObjectiveForm, self ).__init__( *args, **kwargs )
        self.fields['topic'].queryset = Topic.objects.filter( trainee = trainee.id )

    class Meta:
        model = LearningObjective
        fields = ( 'learning_objective', 'topic', )
```

It works fine now, but if something is redundant or unnecessary please tell me :)