# send selected value from Django forms to views.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have to send some data to my database where I have a phone object. For this I need to select the desired phone number and insert data to it in the database. A requirement is to display the phone numbers that belongs to the current login user.

In my form I have 3 textInputs and one MultipleChoiceField where the different phone numbers are displayed. My question is: how can I get the selected phone_num instance on my view.py and send it to my form ?

My view.py:

```
def phone_config(request):
    phone = Phone.objects.get(phone_num = 611111111)
    phone_nums = Phone.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id).values_list('phone_num', flat=True)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = phoneForm(phone_nums, request.POST, instance=phone)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('gracias'))
    else:
        form = phoneForm(phone_nums, instance=phone)
    return render(request, 'heroconfigurer/heroconfigurer.html', {'form': form})


def gracias_view(request):
    return render(request, 'heroconfigurer/gracias.html')
```

My forms.py:

```
class phoneForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        fields = ['phone_num', 'num_calls', 'time_btwn_calls', 'psap']
        widgets = {'phone_num': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), 
                'num_calls': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'time_btwn_calls': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), 
                'psap': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
                  }
        labels = {
                'phone_num': ('Select phone number'),
                'num_calls': ('Number of calls'),
                'time_btwn_calls': ('Time between calls'),
                'psap': ('PSAP'),
        }

    def __init__(self, phone_nums, *args, **kwargs):
        super(tcuForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['phone_num'].queryset = Sim.objects.filter(phone_num__in = phone_nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access any field value in you form in form **cleaned_data**, if the form is valid:

**view.py:**

```
def phone_config(request):
    phone_nums = Phone.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id).values_list('phone_num', flat=True)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = phoneForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            phone_num = form.cleaned_data.get('phone_num') # here you get the selected phone_num
            phone_obj = Phone.objects.get(phone_num=phone_num)

        ... # the rest of the view
```

For more details check [accessing-clean-data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data)

Comment: I need to instance the selected phone number in order to update the data store in the database

Comment: `phone_obj = Phone.objects.get(phone_num=phone_num)` returns you the instance of the phone. `phone_obj` is the instance.

Comment: I can not do that 'phone_num' is referenced before assignment

Comment: How are you doing this ? if you do ` phone_num = form.cleaned_data.get('phone_num') ` then ` phone_obj = Phone.objects.get(phone_num=phone_num)` you can't get such error, only if you are referencing the variable in an other place outside the  if statement: `form.is_valid()`.

Comment: the system doesn't know the phone_num to update the data so it creates a new phone object on the database insted of updating the data on the selected phone_num

Comment: cam make you question clearer, what do you already have, what do you want to update?

Comment: I am sorry if it is not clear.. I am displaying many phone_num in the MultipleChoiceField and when I select a phone_num I need to update/send the data of the 3 textInputs

Comment: I make it working adding this line twice in my code (inside is_valid):  form = phoneForm (phone_nums, request.POST, instance=phone_obj)... I guess that there is a better way